# How access a variable in class which that variable defined in the form

Tags: c#

For example I have a button that get me 3 variable:

```
    private void Savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int A, B, C;
        A = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        B = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        C = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
    }
```

and I have class that use these variable to compute another variable for example:

```
class Class1
{
    public static int MWCompute()
    {
        int MW;
        MW = A * B * C;
        return MW;
    }           
}
```

And again I want to use this MW variable in my form for example:

```
if (something)
{
     textbox4.text = MW.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Your request is unclear, anyway, local variables are local

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without declaring `A, B, C` as static variables, you can call `MWCompute` by passing those variables as parameters and get the result in a local variable `MW`. Then, you can apply your logic in the `if` statement:

```
private void Savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int A, B, C;
    A = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    B = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    C = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);

    int MW = Class1.MWCompute(A, B, C);

    if (something)
    {
        textbox4.text = MW.ToString();
    }
}
```

And `Class1` defined as:

```
class Class1 // as suggested by @Jamiec: give this class a meaningful name
{
    public static int MWCompute(int A, int B, int C)
    {
        int MW;
        MW = A * B * C;
        return MW;
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You typically do this by passing parameters to the class, either in the constructor or in the method itself, as appropriate.

```
class MWCalculator // give it a meaningful name, for starters!
{
    public static int MWCompute(int A, int B, int C)
    {
        int MW;
        MW = A * B * C;
        return MW;
    }           
}
```

Then in your form:

```
private void Savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int A, B, C;
    A = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    B = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    C = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
    var calc = new MwCalculator();
    textBox4.Text = calc.MWCompute(A,B,C).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems related to the scope:

- You can't access non-static variables from a static method without the class instance;
- You can't access method variables from another method.

The solution would be to move `A`, `B` and `C` outside the method and into the class, and make your `MWCompute` method non-static.